# Как правильно настроить псевдокласс :not()?

Tags: html, css, scss

```css
.content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
}

.content :not(.test, .test *) {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.content a, a * {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="box">
    <a href="/">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </a></div>
  <div class="box test">
    <a href="/">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы ссылка  и всё, что внутри неё тоже были в исключении класса .test? нужно чтобы сслыка и текст внутри не был красным, но при этом в других блоках эти стили работали.

Нужно, чтобы весь блок с классом .test был без стилей. Тоесть без бордера, и без бекграунда в элементе со ссылкой. Если ещё проще - первый блок .box со стилями, второй полностью без стилей, чего бы там не было прописано, третий .box со стилями

Comment: а сейчас она разве не в исключении?

Comment: Нет, нужно чтобы сслыка и текст внутри не был красным, но при этом в других блоках эти стили работали.

Comment: ничего не понятно. Какой итоговый результат ожидается?

Comment: Нужно, чтобы весь блок с классом .test был без стилей. Тоесть без бордера, и без бекграунда в элементе со ссылкой.
Если ещё проще - первый блок .box со стилями, второй полностью без стилей, чего бы там не было прописано, третий .box со стилями.

Comment: тогда только отдельным стилем для test и потомков, где все снимается

Comment: Да, можно. Но в даном случае нужно именно только через псевдокласс :not(). Вариант выше я привел для примера. Нужно, чтобы через :not() опускался стиль для .test и все другие стили, которые есть ниже этого блока.

Comment: Это невозможно. Либо тебе нужно добавлять стили :not для всех элементов, в том числе и вложенных

Comment: Но, а если все стили идут выше и .test есть промежуточным классом, всё что ниже - это теги, которые имеют стили от главного класа .content?
А как можно буде добавлять :not для этих элементов исходя только от класса .test?

Comment: Не понял вопрос.

Comment: А как можно буде добавлять :not для этих вложенных элементов исходя только от класса .test?
Беда в том, что все что ниже изменяемо и там только привязка стилей тегов к главному класу .content

Comment: Никак. Надо для каждого случая отдельно прописывать `:not(test)`

Comment: Вообще, кажется что ты делаешь что-то не то, и скорее всего настоящая задача решается намного проще и без `:not`

Comment: Просто задача очень интересная - есть страница, на неё приходит html, который внедряеться в эту страницу. Поверх этого html стоит класс .content, который через теги и important добавляет стили в этот html. Ещё также мне нельзя трогать глобальные стили. В этом html есть блок - .test. Нужно, чтобы к ниму не приходили стили, которые есть в .content. Нужно его просто заблокировать от всего и чтобы там использовались инлайн стили. Я искал разные способы, и iframe, но он не верно работает, и ещё там некоторые варианты, но :not() частично сработал. Единственное - он никак не может перебить внутренний

Comment: точнее внутренние теги некоторые.

Comment: Кстати тегов не так и много. Поэтому возможно, по идеи, их заблокировать, ихние стили. Но как?.. И всё это только от класса .test.

Comment: для блока с классом .test и его потомков переопределить стили на дефолтные (заресетить). `.test, .test * {background:initial;color:initial;border:initial;...}`

Comment: @ValkoBob, никак. То что ты описал нельзя сделать, без ручного присваивания стиля всем элементам которым надо и сбрасывания тем, которым не надо